# How fast is Data.Array?

Tags: arrays, haskell, complexity-theory

The [documentation](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/array-0.3.0.3/Data-Array.html) of `Data.Array` reads:

> Haskell provides indexable arrays, which may be thought of as
>   functions whose domains are isomorphic to contiguous subsets of the
>   integers. Functions restricted in this way can be implemented
>   efficiently; in particular, a programmer may reasonably expect rapid
>   access to the components.

I wonder how fast can `(!)` and `(//)` be. Can I expect O(1) complexity from these, as I would have from their imperative counterparts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, yes, you should be able to expect O(1) from `!` although I'm not sure if thats guaranteed by the standard.

You might want to see the vector package if you want faster arrays though (through use of stream fusion). It is also better designed.

Note that `//` is probably O(n) though because it has to traverse the list (just like an imperative program would). If you need a lot of mutation you can use `MArray` or`MVector`.

Comment: `(//)` is actually linar in the _size of the array_, as it has to make a new copy of the array. Using mutable arrays, however, I would expect it to be linear in the number of updates.

Comment: @hammar it is linear in both, as it must copy the array as well as iterate over the list. // is rather useless, though, in a MArray because you don't need bulk update functionality.

Comment: Yes, of course. However, that only really matters if you're updating some elements more than once.

Comment: So why does your answer say O(1), but your comment says O(n)? :)

Comment: @FredOverflow When I said O(1) I was referring to !, I'll make that more clear